# DevOps Pipeline AKS Deployment with KubeLogin through Service Connection

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I am having AKS kubernetes cluster version 1.26.6. Below is my configuration from Azure Portal. Everything is working great in local. But I like to use Release pipeline and that's where I am getting difficulties.

I have task in rleease pipeline for helm upgrade. I am well aware that we need to use KubeLogin.

I have used azurecli and service principal account in my local. I also have clusterrole and clusterrolebinding applied in my AKS cluster and they all are set up correctly. (I have checked by login and fetching namespaces) in my local.

Now, the only problem I am facing is auto-deployment through the release pipeline. for that, I know we can't use Kubernetes Service Connection as long running token is no longer an option. We need to use Azure Resource Manager and I have configured that in my service connection (with Verify)

However, when It tried to use this service connection with Helm it gave an error. It gives

**Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://brij1111-aks-cluster.azmk8s.io:443/version": getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin not found
It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.
To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
kubelogin is not installed which is required to connect to AAD enabled cluster.
To learn more, please go to https://aka.ms/aks/kubelogin**

Lastly, I am using Azure Hosted Agent rather than my own agent. with Latest Ubuntu image.

Here are some reference screenshots in case you need to guide me correctly...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`Kubelogin`** command tool is not pre-installed on MS hosted agents by default.

To use **`Kubelogin`** command in pipelines, you can use the [**Kubelogin tool installer task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/kubelogin-installer-v0?view=azure-pipelines) to install the latest or specified version of **`Kubelogin`** on the agents every time when running the pipeline job.

Comment: you saved my day. Seriously, there should be an announcement for such breaking changes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @Bright Ran-MSFT is a good solution. Unfortunately, when we implemented it back around April/May 2023, it was not available to us and we used a simple bash stage to use CURL to download the .zip package for Kubelogin, extract it and use it.

```bash
echo "Downloading kubelogin binary"
curl -LO "https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin/releases/download/v0.0.25/kubelogin-linux-amd64.zip"
echo "uzipping it."
unzip -j "kubelogin-linux-amd64.zip" -d /usr/local/bin
echo "removing the zip file."
rm -f "kubelogin-linux-amd64.zip"
kubelogin --version
```

Also, one more suggestion will be to ditch the Service.